# Init script returning file not found

Tags: shell, raspbian

I'm using a Raspbian OS and I created a simple shell script to initiate with OS. I put this script in /etc/init.d.

```
#! /bin/sh

case "$1" in
   start)
   echo "Starting script"
   /etc/init.d/search_files.sh

   ;;

 stop)
   echo "Stopping script"
   killall search_files
   ;;
 *)
    exit 1
    ;;
esac

exit 0
```

This script should call another script, in the same folder, which will be executed in a infinite loop and will verify the amount of files in a folder (Videos).

```
#!/bin/sh

while true
do 
    if [ $(ls -1A /home/pi/Videos | wc -l) -gt 0 ];
    then omxplayer -p -o local --aspect-mode fill 2016_10_31_TESTE$(ls -1A /home/pi/Videos | wc -l).mp4;
    fi
done
```

The scripts works apart however when the OS started the script is executed but the message

> `File 2016_10_31_TESTE1.mp4 not found`

is displayed but the file is in folder.

I gave the permission 755 to both scripts.

what am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: add a `cd /full/path/to/videos` in your calling script? If that doesn't work, move it the 2ndary script. Good luck.

Comment: This worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to use absolute path the below for second script; also declare a variable `DIR` to store it:

```
#!/bin/sh
DIR="/home/pi/Videos"
while true
do 
  if [ $(ls -1A ${DIR} | wc -l) -gt 0 ];
  then 
    omxplayer -p -o local --aspect-mode fill ${DIR}/2016_10_31_TESTE$(ls -1A ${DIR} | wc -l).mp4;
  fi
done
```

Note: also check you execute `sh` and not something else from `init.d`. If it's not the case, or if unsure, you may rather call the second script this way:

```
...
case "$1" in
   start)
   echo "Starting script"
   /bin/sh /etc/init.d/search_files.sh
```